# How can i access to the Value that i scraped and Add it to my DataGrid? Pls Look at the screenshot

Tags: c#, arrays, web-scraping, datagrid, href

```
public void ScrapeData(string page)
        {
            var web = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = web.Load(page);

            var Articles = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class = 'b-product-grid-tile js-tile-container']");
          

 


            foreach (var article in Articles)
            {
                var Sneaker = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(article.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class ='b-product-tile-link js-product-tile-link']").InnerText);
                var Preis = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(article.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class ='b-product-tile-price']").InnerText);
                var hrefList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a").Select(p => p.GetAttributeValue("href", "not found"));
                Debug.Print(Sneaker + Preis + hrefList);

                _entries.Add(new EntryModel { Products = Sneaker, Preis = Preis, Link = hrefList }); // can´t convert string implicitly (Sory i have Visual Studio in German i try to translate the Error) 
                
            }
```

[All the Links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyx3d.png) But how can i access to them? and get them in my DataGrid

**I found the Links but idk how i access to them and get it into my DataGrid**

**After i add .ToArray i got the same problem the Debugger Print alwayse (System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode,System.String])**

**Here some screenshots of the edited code**

[Same Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYcrs.png)

[The Edit Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CehuM.png)

**And again i am very sorry how i ask my questions i am very new and i am happy if you correct me**

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear which of the links you want; you've highlighted only one. However if you do:

```
var hrefList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a")
  .Select(p => p.GetAttributeValue("href", "not found"))
  .ToArray();
```

(added .ToArray())

Then you can access e.g. the second one via `hrefList[1]`

If you only ever want the second one you;d be better off doing:

```
 var href = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a")
   .Select(p => p.GetAttributeValue("href", "not found"))
   .Skip(1)
   .First();
```

No need to copy the whole lot to an array if all you want is one

Comment: Hi ty for the fast Answer but if i Debug.Print(hrefList) i just get (System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode,System.String])

Comment: Sory for the bad highlighed link. The first Link i want to access is [44] and than alwayse Skip 3 Links(bc there are 3 time the same Link).

Comment: *if i Debug.Print(hrefList) i just get ...* - did you follow my advice to add a `ToArray()` ? If you call ToArray, then Debug.Print(hrefList) should tell you it's an array of string, not a WhereSelectEnumerableIterator

Comment: And then when you have it as an array you can access index 44, and then 47 or 48 (I couldnt understand "skip 3 because there are 3 same" - it is wrong by 1 index - If there are 3 same and you want the first but not the other 2, you take the first at index 44 and skip 45 and also 46 and next you want is at 47. If there are 4 same you take 48. If you don't want 44 then just go straight to 47/48.. whatever you want, it's simple to just get what you want from the array but you must `ToArray()` first

Comment: i edited my question and add some screenshots if you have time can you look at it?

Comment: But, that Debug.Print prints more than just hrefList[44] or whatever. It prints other things like Sneaker and Preis so I'm not sure (unless theyre null or empty) how the printed string can start with what is claimed.. Just do a sole `Debug.Print(hrefList[1])` to prove whether calling ToArray worked out for hrefList

Comment: Also I just noticed in your screenshot that you used hrefList on the last line but it has a red line underneath it which means that it's a compiler error and the code won't run. Normally in this case visual studio asks a question like "The code didn't compile, do you want to run the previous version that did compile?" - say NO and fix the error. If you say YES then all youre doing is re-running the OLD exe that didn't have ToArray compiled into it

Comment: Ok i just found out that i run the OLD exe but why it don´t do the Updated version of my code and how i can change that?

Comment: You're not really reading what I saying, I think.. it doesn't do the updates version because your code has an error and does not compile. Fix the error so that the code compiles